# Google Tag Manager Not Sending events in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

This is how I declared google tag manager container

```
self.tagManager = [TAGManager instance];
[self.tagManager.logger setLogLevel:kTAGLoggerLogLevelVerbose];

[TAGContainerOpener openContainerWithId:@"GTM-XXXX"   // Update with your Container ID.
                             tagManager:self.tagManager
                               openType:kTAGOpenTypePreferFresh
                                timeout:nil
                               notifier:self];
```

Below Is my debugger result

```
 GoogleTagManager info: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:208): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1
```

Why this error is coming ,Please help

Answer (score 0):

I see the same in my logs but events are getting sent.

```
2015-06-03 15:25:12.313 MyApp[49369:487639] GTM Info: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:226): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1
2015-06-03 15:25:12.314 MyApp[49369:487711] GTM Info: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:529): hit(s) Successfully deleted
2015-06-03 15:25:12.316 MyApp[49369:487711] GTM Info: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:237): 1 hit(s) sent
```

and I can see events in GA